# Symfony 2 propel:build-model not showing errors?

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I am trying to build models like this:

`php app/console propel:build-model --verbose`

And I am getting:

> [Propel] You are running the command: propel:build-model
>
> [Propel] Error
>
> An error has occured during the "om" task process. To get more
>   details, run the command with the "--verbose" option.

How can I see the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded to PHP 5.3 and now it works.

Comment: If this is an issue with PHP 5.4, would you check that a bug has been logged? I'm guessing it's a Propel issue rather than a Symfony2 issue.

Comment: I have same issue on PHP 5.5 but I think downgrading isn't reasonable solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, it came from the fact that I had forgotten to define a primary key in a table .